# What is "manually dependency injection"?

Tags: dependency-injection

I've often read of this phrase in the context of IOC-frameworks.

In their examples they basically have a code sequence where they create a bunch of objects, connect them, etc. and then do some stuff.

What I don't understand is why you would need this sequence when you follow the principles of object oriented programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a few words — Dependency Injection is a concept.
Classical OOP Object resolves their own dependencies and manage them. So a classical class needs to bring knowledge about it's environment which aren't necessary for its real cause. Dependency injection communicates the responsibility for creating and linking to an independent instance which makes it easier to maintain the code if there are tons of classes.

But you're right — finally if there's something to implement and it's endles time needed to create objects in classes — following principles of object oriented programming identifies this effort and serve instances to manage this job.

Comment: I thought a classical class follows the single responsibility principle?

Comment: It can, but a different principle is at work here: [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP). A class can follow the SRP while still tightly coupling itself to its dependencies. The SRP influences which collaborators a class may have; the DIP influences how the class acquires those collaborators. (Dependency injection is just one technique that is used when following the DIP.)